# iOS Widget for turning Wi-Fi on/off

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, control-center

Is there a widget for turning on and off Wi-Fi? I have to open up the settings and go to Wi-Fi to switch it off. For me, this is annoying and unacceptable. Just can't live with it.

I know:

- What the Wi-Fi button on Control Center does
- Control Center's behaviour has changed since iOS 11 update
- How to turn off Wi-Fi from the Settings app

I just want quick access to WiFi toggle like on Android.

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps cannot control Wi-Fi, so it is not possible for an app to provide a Today widget to change the Wi-Fi power.

If your device is jailbroken, you can install [<sub>[image]</sub> **RealCC**](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.jakeashacks.realcc/), which makes the toggles in Control Center for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth control the power rather than connections.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your device is jailbroken this is not possible. If your device has Siri enabled you can ask Siri to enable/disable WiFi but that's about it.